# i downloaded a flutter project from a friend and i got this error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**strong text**

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:google_fonts
- package:http
- package:http_parser

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/circle_avatar.dart:108:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? backgroundImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/circle_avatar.dart:113:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? foregroundImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:185:14: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
required ImageProvider image,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:336:14: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
required ImageConfiguration configuration,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:369:3: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration get configuration => _configuration;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:370:3: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration _configuration;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:371:21: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
set configuration(ImageConfiguration value) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:210:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? activeThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:219:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? inactiveThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:530:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? activeThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:532:9: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
final ImageProvider? inactiveThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:795:3: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
ImageProvider? get activeThumbImage => _activeThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:796:3: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
ImageProvider? _activeThumbImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:797:24: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
set activeThumbImage(ImageProvider? value) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:814:3: Error: Type 'ImageProvider' not found.
ImageProvider? get inactiveThumbImage => _inactiveThumbImage;

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:110:36: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode) => imageProvider.load(key, decode);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:113:23: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
Future obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) => imageProvider.obtainKey(configuration);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:915:44: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2088:5: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration configuration = ImageConfiguration.empty,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2132:3: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration get configuration => _configuration;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2133:3: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration _configuration;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2134:21: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
set configuration(ImageConfiguration value) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/table.dart:376:5: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration configuration = ImageConfiguration.empty,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/table.dart:552:3: Error: Type 'ImageConfiguration' not found.
ImageConfiguration get configuration => _configuration;

```
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/circle_avatar.dart:113:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
final ImageProvider? foregroundImage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart:81:42: Error: The method 'ImageConfiguration' isn't defined for the class '_DropdownMenuPainter'.

- '_DropdownMenuPainter' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ImageConfiguration'.
  _painter.paint(canvas, rect.topLeft, ImageConfiguration(size: rect.size));
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:185:14: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  required ImageProvider image,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:336:14: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  required ImageConfiguration configuration,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:370:3: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  ImageConfiguration _configuration;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:371:21: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  set configuration(ImageConfiguration value) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:394:11: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  final ImageConfiguration sizedConfiguration = configuration.copyWith(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:210:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? activeThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:219:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? inactiveThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:530:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? activeThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:532:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? inactiveThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:796:3: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  ImageProvider? _activeThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:797:24: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  set activeThumbImage(ImageProvider? value) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:815:3: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  ImageProvider? _inactiveThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:816:26: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  set inactiveThumbImage(ImageProvider? value) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:854:3: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  ImageConfiguration? _configuration;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:855:21: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  set configuration(ImageConfiguration value) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:904:3: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  ImageProvider? _cachedThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:908:60: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  BoxDecoration _createDefaultThumbDecoration(Color color, ImageProvider? image, ImageErrorListener? errorListener) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:950:11: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? thumbImage = isEnabled
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart:1018:5: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  ImageProvider? thumbImage,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch_list_tile.dart:265:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? activeThumbImage;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch_list_tile.dart:270:9: Error: 'ImageProvider' isn't a type.
  final ImageProvider? inactiveThumbImage;

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutt
**strong text**er/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:283:41: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
Future obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:291:15: Error: 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't a type.
Completer? completer;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:292:12: Error: 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't a type.
Future? result;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:302:15: Error: 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't a type.
final AssetBundleImageKey key = AssetBundleImageKey(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:317:38: Error: 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't a type.
result = SynchronousFuture(key);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:334:27: Error: 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't a type.
completer = Completer();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:302:41: Error: The method 'AssetBundleImageKey' isn't defined for the class 'AssetImage'.

- 'AssetImage' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'AssetBundleImageKey'.
  final AssetBundleImageKey key = AssetBundleImageKey(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:351:39: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  String? _chooseVariant(String main, ImageConfiguration config, List? candidates) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/shape_decoration.dart:365:35: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  void _paintImage(Canvas canvas, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/shape_decoration.dart:379:44: Error: 'ImageConfiguration' isn't a type.
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: update your flutter version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the same flutter version your friend use. I think yours version is greater. Ask your friend to send you `flutter doctor` output and make your flutter version the same.

FVM might be a suitable tool for this (install a needed version without deleting your own): https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation

Then simply run:

```
fvm install [version of your friend]
fvm use [version]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable null-safety and run the project with the following cmd:

```
 flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```